# Validating if objects have been selected in a ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a `def clean(self):` function, to validate if my objects have been selected.
This is my Code so far:

```
class Malfunction(models.Model):
    malfunction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    malfunction = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)  
    information = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, 
                                                   blank=True)
    is_important = models.BooleanField()

class Situation(models.Model):
    considered_malfunctions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Malfunction, 
        related_name='Situations', 
        limit_choices_to={'is_important': True},) 
    
    reason = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        ???
```

so my clean function should check if an "is_important"-object from Functions is not selected. Then the TextField in reason must be filled.
If every object got selected, there is no need for a text in reason.

i thought of something like:

```
def clean(self):
    picked_malfunctions = self.considered_malfunctions.all()
    missing_argument = []
    not_picked_malfunctions = 
                       Malfunktion.objects.exclude(Situations=self)
```